# Force Selenium to start with an old ChromeDriver version

Tags: python, selenium

My ChromeDriver's version is a bit late compared to my Google Chrome browser, and it doesn't initialize the requested webpage until I use the right driver.
Is there a workaround to worry free about this problem? Or I have to babysit it every time my browser auto-updates itself?

Answer (score 1):

The chromedriver exe and Chrome Browser exe has to match according to Chromium:

```
Each version of ChromeDriver supports Chrome with matching major, minor, and build version numbers. For example, ChromeDriver 73.0.3683.20 supports all Chrome versions that start with 73.0.3683.
```

via https://chromedriver.chromium.org/